# Returning objects instead of strings in RCTAutoComplete

Tags: autocomplete, react-native

I've implemented [RCTAutoComplete](https://github.com/nulrich/RCTAutoComplete) in my React Native app and have it working just as the demo does:

```
onTyping: function (text) {

    var countries = Countries.filter(function (country) {
        return country.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(text.toLowerCase())
    }).map(function (country) {
        return country.name;
    });

    this.setState({
        data:  countries
    });
},
```

However, I want it to return the country's ID once clicked, rather than the country's name. when I use an array of objects as the data source, it returns this error:

> Exception thrown while executing UI block: MLPAutoCompleteTextField expects an array with objects that are either strings or conform to the MLPAutoCompletionObject protocol for possible completions."`

Not sure how to implement the "MLPAutoCompletionObject protocol."

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C protocols are similar to Java/C# Interfaces.  You can find out what properties to implement by looking at the header file for MLPAutoCompletionObject:

https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField/blob/master/MLPAutoCompleteTextField/MLPAutoCompletionObject.h

TLDR: It would appear that your objects each need a property named `autocompleteString`